# TFS build get label if exists else latest?

Tags: tfs

I'm specifying a label in the "Get Version" property of a TFS 2012 build definition:

Get Version: LMyLabel

However, if MyLabel doesn't exist, the build fails with this error message:

Exception Message: TF14064: Could not find label MyLabel@*. (type LabelNotFoundException)

How can I configure the build to default to the latest code if MyLabel doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to customise the template.

Locate the Get Workspace Activity

[image: Get Workspace Activity]

Note that it's properties has the GetVersion Argument

[image: Get Workspace Activity Properties]

Now add a Try Catch Activity, where the current Get Workspace Activity resides

[image: try catch]

Copy the original Get Workspace Activity to the Try.

Copy the Get Workspace Activity and place it in the catch, Set the catch to Exception

[image: Catch of Try Catch Activity]

In the Properties of you Get Workspace Activity set the VersionOverride value to be blank.

This should now try and Donwload the source for a label you supply, if that label is not present then the catch should be hit and you should then download the latest code.

This was done on the fly and may need some minor tweeking!

Comment: Thank you for the great, detailed answer. I tried exactly what you said except that in the VersionOverride in the Try branch I specified "LMyLabel". I'm still getting the LabelNotFoundException as described in the question above. I'm wondering if the TryCatch doesn't work at all... or just doesn't work in the this context. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe another way to solve this problem would be to do an If check to see if MyLabel exists? Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking at it. I get the same response, the error is thrown and the build stopped before it hits the Catch. I'll do some more research and testing, but won't be near a TFS box before Monday

Comment: yes you could add something like a PS script with a Call out to TF Labels "MyLabel" and then catch the response to determine if the label exists and then add an IF and switch the flow based on the response. bit busy today, if i get time i will run some more tests